# MySql - Get duplicates by multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I have an part inventory table that stores parts by PartName, WarehouseId, VendorCode (main interest columns). It should only have unique PartName entries by WarehouseId and VendorCode. However, entries are mixed, and I need to get the PartName, WarehouseId and Vendor for such a case. E.g:

```
ABC133, Warehouse 10, VendorCode 1234
ABC133, Warehouse 10, VendorCode 1222

BBB111, Warehouse 20, VendorCode 1111
BBB111, Warehouse 20, VendorCode 2222
```

I have customized a query found on this site to do this, but it only brings the first "duplicate" for every duplicate PartName, and I need to get all the faulty entries:

```
ABC133, Warehouse 10, VendorCode 1222

BBB111, Warehouse 20, VendorCode 1111
```

This is the query I use:

```
SELECT i.MFGPN, i.VendorCode, i.WarehouseID FROM edi_846_inventory i
INNER JOIN (SELECT MFGPN FROM edi_846_inventory 
GROUP BY MFGPN HAVING count(MFGPN) > 1 and count(VendorCode) > 1) dup ON i.MFGPN = dup.MFGPN
where MFGPN is the PartName
```

Thanks

Comment: Out of `ABC133, Warehouse 10, VendorCode 1234 -  ABC133, Warehouse 10, VendorCode 1222` two how you decide 2nd one is duplicate is there a primary key or datetime column to identify which entry happened earlier ?

Comment: I should have unique PartNumber + WarehouseId + VendorCode; there should only be 1 and only 1 Vendor Code for a PartNumber and Warehouse

Answer (score 0):

This is the query that you want:

```
SELECT i.MFGPN, i.VendorCode, i.WarehouseID
FROM edi_846_inventory i INNER JOIN
     (SELECT MFGPN, WarehouseID
      FROM edi_846_inventory 
      GROUP BY MFGPN, WarehouseID
      HAVING count(*) > 1 
     ) dup
     ON i.MFGPN = dup.MFGPN AND i.WarehouseID = dup.WarehouseID;
```

In other words, your subquery needs to aggregate by both `MFGPN` and `WarehouseID`.

Also, just concatenating the vendors together might be sufficient for you:

```
      SELECT MFGPN, WarehouseID, GROUP_CONCAT(VendorCode) as Vendors
      FROM edi_846_inventory 
      GROUP BY MFGPN, WarehouseID
      HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

A work colleague found a solution:

select i.MFGPN, i.WarehouseID, i.VendorCode, i.IngramSKU

from edi_846_inventory i
  where i.MFGPN in
  (
   select * 
   from
   (
    select distinct i.MFGPN
    from edi_846_inventory i
    group by i.MFGPN, i.WarehouseID
    having count(*) > 1
   ) dup
  )
  order by i.MFGPN, i.WarehouseID